# how to fix Incorrect syntax near '('

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table biketrip  as (
select*from bike..['202301-divvy-tripdata$']
union all
select* 
from bike..['202302-divvy-tripdata$']
union all
select* 
from bike..['202303-divvy-tripdata$']
union all
select* 
from bike..['202304-divvy-tripdata$']
union all
select* 
from bike..['202305-divvy-tripdata$']
union all
select* 
from bike..['202306-divvy-tripdata$']

)
```

this code do not work and I get the following message :Incorrect syntax near '('.

I want to combining all the 6 months data tables into a single table

Comment: You should always read the official documentation before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

The CREATE TABLE AS syntax is not universally supported, you could instead opt for the SELECT INTO instead.

```
SELECT *
INTO biketrip
FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM bike.[202301-divvy-tripdata$]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM bike.[202302-divvy-tripdata$]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM bike.[202303-divvy-tripdata$]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM bike.[202304-divvy-tripdata$]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM bike.[202305-divvy-tripdata$]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM bike.[202306-divvy-tripdata$]
) AS combinedData;
```

Comment: I assumed he is using Microsoft SQL, hence the MSSQL in my comment.

Comment: I see, I assumed SQL covered all kinds of SQL, however I realise now SQL-Server is specific to Microsoft SQL. Thanks